# How to DataBricks read Delta tables based on incremental data

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

we have to read the data from delta table and then we are joining the all the tables based on our requirements, then we would have to call the our internal APIS to pass the each row data. this is our goal. there is another one requirement, we would have to read bulk data is first time only, the second time we have to read changes or updated data from source of the delta tables. kindly help us, how to implement this senario.

bulk load code, as below format.

```
a = spark.table("tablename1")
b = spark.table("tablename2")
c = spark.table("tablename3")

final_df = spark.sql(" joinig 3 dataframe as per our requirement")
```

Calling APIS for each row in above that dataframe "final_df"

now, we could not use changedata properties for source tables. is it possible to read incremental data any timestamp manner or any customer implementation, kindly share to us.

Thanks

Comment: How you are doing join here?

Comment: each table as one dataframe and using df..selectExpr("select column").join(df2.selectExpr("select column")) ....etc

Comment: You can load incrementlly with using the delta version. but each time you need to run the code, it doesn't load automatically as it is done in changedata capture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below functions to load latest data, this doesn't load data automatically you need run it whenever new data occurs.

First, do bulk load.

```
from delta.tables import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

def bulk_load(table1,table2,table3):
    tbl1Dict = {
        "path":table1,
        "data":spark.table(f"delta.`{table1}`"),
        "max_timestamp":DeltaTable.forPath(spark,path=f"{table1}").history().selectExpr("max(timestamp)").collect()[0][0]
        }
        
     tbl2Dict = {
         "path":table2,
         "data":spark.table(f"delta.`{table2}`"),
         "max_timestamp":DeltaTable.forPath(spark,path=f"{table2}").history().selectExpr("max(timestamp)").collect()[0][0]
         }
         
    tbl3Dict = {
        "path":table3,
        "data":spark.table(f"delta.`{table3}`"),
        "max_timestamp":DeltaTable.forPath(spark,path=f"{table3}").history().selectExpr("max(timestamp)").collect()[0][0]
        }
        
    return tbl1Dict,tbl2Dict,tbl3Dict
```

This gives you the dictionary having **path**, **data** and **max_timestamp**.
Use these return values in your join query by getting value from **data** key.

```
tbl1,tbl2,tbl3 = bulk_load("/delta_df_1/","/delta_df_2/","/delta_df_3/")
tbl1["data"].show()
tbl2["data"].show()
tbl3["data"].show()
```

[image]

Next pass this dictionary to **increment_load** function which gives you the same structure dictionary having latest records.

```
def increment_load(table1,table2,table3):
    tblDict1 = {
        "path":table1["path"],
        "data":spark.table(f'delta.`{table1["path"]}`').select("*","_metadata.file_modification_time").filter(col("file_modification_time")>table1["max_timestamp"]),
        "max_timestamp":DeltaTable.forPath(spark,path=f'{table1["path"]}').history().selectExpr("max(timestamp)").collect()[0][0]
        }
        
    tblDict2 = {
        "path":table2["path"],
        "data":spark.table(f'delta.`{table2["path"]}`').select("*","_metadata.file_modification_time").filter(col("file_modification_time")>table2["max_timestamp"]),
        "max_timestamp":DeltaTable.forPath(spark,path=f'{table2["path"]}').history().selectExpr("max(timestamp)").collect()[0][0]
        }
        
    tblDict3 = {
        "path":table3["path"],
        "data":spark.table(f'delta.`{table3["path"]}`').select("*","_metadata.file_modification_time").filter(col("file_modification_time")>table3["max_timestamp"]),
        "max_timestamp":DeltaTable.forPath(spark,path=f'{table3["path"]}').history().selectExpr("max(timestamp)").collect()[0][0]
        }
        
    return tblDict1,tblDict2,tblDict3
```

This function gets the records having **file_modification_time** greater than the previous timestamp. That is the latest record.

After, bulk load you having `tbl1`,`tbl2` and `tbl3` variables.
If you do increment load you will get empty results as we did not write any data.

[image]

Now let us write some data to these 3 tables.
Below is the data written.

[image]

Now, do increment load.

```
inc_tbl1,inc_tbl2,inc_tbl3 = increment_load(tbl1,tbl2,tbl3)
```

Output:

[image]
Here, you can see data latest record is fetched.

Then you can use this in your join operation and Api calls.
Remember while calling increment load function with dict tables with previous loaded data.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. In databricks notebook, this would work only when we have active cluster session throughout the process or else tbl1,tbl2 ... will be unknown if cluster is inactive, am i right ? In that case what could be the solution ?

Comment: The cluster should be running. without server how can you access data from server. To avoid cluster active you create pipeline job and schedule it. after task completion cluster will be inactive

Comment: My point is, tbl1, tbl2 ... are the outputs from bulk load. If after once bulk load, the pipeline is scheduled to run each day or any other regular schedules for increment load only, then tbl1, tbl2... will be showing as unknown variable because cluster might be inactive  and need restarts which lose the value of tbl1, tbl2.. ? so how we separate bulk load and increment load here? We cannot keep the cluster active for all time right, it is not efficient too?

Comment: Yeah. data will be gone when cluster stopped but every time you need to do  once bulk load and go for increment load. But for you scenario you should be knowing what the last loaded data timestamp. without that we can not do incremental. better to use autoloader. since it use checkpoints.